# Scala.js convert Dynamic to scala type

Tags: scala.js

Is there a way to convert a js Dynaimc type to a desired Scala type like String, Int, Double or BigDecimal?

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/blob/master/library/src/main/scala/scala/scalajs/js/Dynamic.scala) there does not appear to be a way in the companion object to do these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.  You must use `asInstanceOf[T]`.

For example

if you have some object called data with an id of Int and name of String

```
val myPromise = $.ajax(url)

myPromise.done((data: js.Dynamic, textStatus: String, jqXHr: JQueryXHR) => {
  val id = data.id.asInstanceOf[Int]
  val name = data.name.asInstanceOf[String]
})
```

Comment: Correct -- Scala.js, specifically the interface between JavaScript and Scala, is pretty much the one place where heavy use of `isInstanceOf` is totally normal and idiomatic.  It even makes sense there: the compiler doesn't know what the actual type is, so you are instructing it, based on external knowledge.